# File format supported by windows media player component

Tags: axwindowsmediaplayer

I m developing media player in c# and I m using **windows media player component** for that..

This is my code

```
private void songList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = paths[songList.SelectedIndex];
}
```

Can anyone tell me the supported file formats for this component?
The *version information property of the component is '12.0.7600.16385'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this microsoft website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316992) for the supported file formates. All the file formats are listed and the compatible windows media player versions.